# can a table have two foreign keys of the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have one table named Registration and another table named Login. I want to fetch ID and Type columns of Registration table into Login table. Can I do it with Foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, if this composite foreign key corresponds to a composite primary key in the referenced table. You can also do that if the referenced table has a unique index on the two columns.